# Not able to link to shared library of OpenCV (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv

The problem written below the line is solved but i m facing a new related problem.
Slightly different from before, I am compiling and linking the sample OpenCV code as:

```
g++ facedetect.cpp -o facedetection -I /home/harsh/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/include/opencv/ -L/home/harsh/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/lib/ -lcv -lcxcore -lcvaux -lml -lhighgui
```

That doesn't give any errors now, but when I run the executable using

```
./facedetection
```

i get this error:

```
./facedetection: error while loading shared libraries: libcv.so.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And when I do symbolic linking, using:

```
ln -s libcv.so libcv.so.2.0
```

Then the error is:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libcv.so.2.0': File exists
```

Don't know how to get around this.

Thanks in advance..

<strike>IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</strike>

I am trying to create a linux executable of a sample OpenCV program that will be linked dynamically with .so files and will be executed on a machine where OpenCV is **not** installed, but the .so files will be present on that linux machine.

I have searched many posts regarding this but still am unsuccessful.

I compiled opencv like this:

```
cd OpenCV-2.0.0/
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .
make
```

Then all the compiled libraries were created in OpenCV-2.0.0/lib

Then, in the samples/c directory, I did this:

```
g++ facedetect.cpp -o facedetection -I /home/harsh/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/include/opencv/ -L/home/harsh/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/lib/ -llibcv -llibcxcore -llibcvaux -llibml -llibhighgui
```

But Errors are :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcxcore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcvaux
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibml
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibhighgui
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Harsh - You've asked a bunch of questions and many of them have good answers. You should reward the answerers with some rep and a checkmark by marking some of them as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-lcv`, `-lcxcore`, etc.

To link to `libfoo.so`, the flag is `-lfoo`, without the `lib` part.

If your libraries aren't in the default runtime library search path (how this is set/managed depends on your OS and distribution), you need to inform the dynamic linker as to where they are located. (Just like you have to do so when you compile by adding `-L` flags.)

On Linux, this is done by setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, e.g.:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/harsh/Downloads/OpenCV-2.0.0/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./your_app
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mat, do you have any idea about my new issue?

Comment: Edited, but please do some research, that's ask and answered very, very often.